# My Org's IP address is not in the given IP Range

Tags: rest-api, callout, ip

The list of IP ranges to be whitelisted are (as far as I know the followings): https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1 -
however my call is sent out from an IP Address (check if You don't trust: 35.157.191.28 ), which is nowhere on this list, so my API call was totally ignored (the response is empty without errormsg or even http status code) because according to the integrated system's inner logs we "matched none of the trusted IPs".
What does it mean? What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] of this site and go thru the [help], [ask] articles. This being your first question, decent job wrt to the question details but it can be improved further. With the current details and certain assumptions, check if my answer holds true in your case. If not, then please [edit] your question and improve it more specific ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your instance is on Hyperforce, the following would be worth visiting (*Otherwise, this answer is irrelevant*).

**1. What does it mean?**

This would most likely mean that you are a hyperforce customer. Your salesforce instance could no more be hosted in Salesforce-Managed Instances or Public Cloud Instances, but on Hyperforce Instances. To find out if you are hyperforce customer, locate your `Instance ID` from *Setup* > *Company Information* page, and verify in the Hyperforce instances listed [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314281&type=1).

As mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1),

> **If you are a Hyperforce customer**, Salesforce will no longer publish IP addresses for Hyperforce customers. In addition to the IP
> ranges below, you should follow our recommendations as outlined in the
> [**Retain uninterrupted access to Salesforce
> services**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363860&type=1)
> on Hyperforce article.

This could be the possible reason for why you are unable to locate your IP address [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1).

**2. What should I do?**

As recommended by Salesforce, you should move away from hard-coded IP allowlists or hard-coded instance specific references and instead allow required domains (including the salesforce myDomain). Some useful references mentioned below:

[Retain uninterrupted access to Salesforce services on Hyperforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363860&type=1)

> **Don’t Use Hard-Coded IP Allowlists** IP allowlisting historically was used as a low-tech form of security to prevent internet traffic
> from being rerouted. This strategy requires vigilant maintenance when
> new instances and servers come online. As Hyperforce rapidly scales,
> the manual overhead of this approach will become unmanageable for
> customers. So, Hyperforce IPs aren’t published, and allowlisting isn’t
> supported.
>
> Users benefit from replacing fragile IP allowlists with modern and
> sustainable approaches to security. The next section describes common
> reasons for allowlisting and recommended alternatives.
>
> **Control User and API Client Access to Salesforce Services** If you use IP allowlists to control user or server access to the internet,
> then Allow the Required Domains.
>
> Secure access to these domains is enforced through the use of HTTPS
> and SSL client certificates.

You might find some more useful information in these links: [Hyperforce - General FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356459&type=1), [Updating Hard-coded references](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335670&type=1) & [Allow the Required Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.setup_domains.htm&type=5)

*With the minimal details in your question, explaining more towards all the details related to Hyperforce is beyond the scope of this question.*

*Disclaimer: I'm neither an expert on networking nor on Hyperforce. I've not gone thru all text in the aforementioned articles, but some of it will be relevant to your question (provided you are in Hyperforce)*

Comment: Thank You Arut! You have been most helpful! Indeed my instance is Hyperforce. So we are thinking about using some self-signed certificate and add it to the http request by this method: HttpRequest class' setClientCertificateName() method, will see to what end...

Comment: If you are using outbound messages or named credentials for making callouts, you can configure self signed certificates and defining them under the api certificate section (under certificate & key management) or from named credentials configuration page. Better to use OOB approach over apex in this case.

Comment: Yes, I guess you mean by out of the box approach, that: 
first I should use the built-in Setup menu to create the credential, and then I need apex only to assign it to the http request? Or is there an other way to certify the request?

Comment: You are right about the approach. After you define Named credential and start using the same in apex, all the certificate related configuration can be done OOB. You need not use setClientCertificateName().

Comment: Yeah, but wait: how should I use it in apex, if not without the setClientCertificateName() method? You mean: 
a, the certification is automatically attached to the request 
b, or should be attached in the code on some other way?
I thought the OOB approach is covered, by this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm

Comment: Under `Named Credential > Authentication > Certificate` lookup, you can specify any certificate present already in `Certificate and Key Management` and it should  automatically get used in HTTP Requests if you are using a named credential callout in apex. I believe `setClientCertificateName()` is used when don't use a named credential callout or want  to specify any certificate present in `Certificate and Key Management`. *Disclaimer: I have minor doubt on this though; its been a while I tried this out and could have changed with Salesforce releases.*

Comment: Found it :) Thanks a lot!!!